# Return value from method to main did not display correctly

Tags: java, class, methods

I build a program using JAVA to receive input from user to calculate their BMI and pass those values to another method name calculateBMI(). The problem currently is that when I want to return back the BMI to the main method, it will display the output as 0.0. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentBMI{


//METHOD
      static float calculateBMI(float weight, float height){

        float bmi;

        System.out.println("Your weight in KG is: " + weight);
        System.out.println("Your height in M² is: " + (height/100));
        return bmi = weight / (height/100)*(height/100);


        }

//MAIN
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        float bmi=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please insert your weight in KG: ");
        float weight = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Please insert your height in CM: ");
        float height = input.nextFloat();

        calculateBMI(weight, height);

        System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + bmi);

      }
}
```

The reason why I declared and initialized the value BMI as 0 in main method because when I declared without initialized it, console return error to initialized that variable but to be honest I'm not very sure about that one. Can anyone help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: You're not assigning the function's result to your `bmi` variable.

Comment: You need to assign returned value to some variable. `bmi` in main isn't the same as `bmi` in the method.

Comment: @daniu sorry totally forgot about that. Thanks for the solution

Comment: @Amongalen already declared one in the main

Comment: I think your BMI calculation is wrong. If I remember correctly, it should be `weight / ((height/100)*(height/100))` (note the additional parentheses).

Comment: @MCEmperor yes the formula was wrong, and already fixed. Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First return the bmi value in your method without assignment.

Assign the return value to the bmi variable in the main mathod:

```
  //METHOD
  static float calculateBMI(float weight, float height){



    System.out.println("Your weight in KG is: " + weight);
    System.out.println("Your height in M² is: " + (height/100));
    return  weight / (height/100)*(height/100);


    }

//MAIN

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    float bmi=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please insert your weight in KG: ");
    float weight = input.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Please insert your height in CM: ");
    float height = input.nextFloat();

    bmi = calculateBMI(weight, height);

    System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + bmi);

  }
```

Comment: I try to use your solution but turns out it give output of the weight input.

Comment: @DarlisaCardiff maybe because yor bmi calculation is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the bmi in your method. Assigning in the method will not reflect in your main method since it is not class variable or static variable.

The main method's bmi variable should get assignment of the method result.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentBMI{

//METHOD
      static float calculateBMI(float weight, float height){

          System.out.println("Your weight in KG is: " + weight);
          System.out.println("Your height in M² is: " + (height/100));
          return weight / (height/100)*(height/100);

        }

//MAIN
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        float bmi=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please insert your weight in KG: ");
        float weight = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Please insert your height in CM: ");
        float height = input.nextFloat();

        bmi = calculateBMI(weight, height);

        System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + bmi);

      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//your code return wrong value.you can check mine and compare it to your code

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentBMI{

```
  static float calculateBMI(float weight, float height){

    float bmi;
    float calc;

    System.out.println("Your weight in KG is: " + weight);
    System.out.println("Your height in M² is: " + (height/100));
    calc=(height/100)*(height/100);
    bmi=weight/calc;
    return bmi;


    }
```

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    float bmi=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please insert your weight in KG: ");
    float weight = input.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Please insert your height in CM: ");
    float height = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + calculateBMI(weight, height));

  }
```

}